# How do I change timezone in AppMaker Environment?

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm getting an incorrect time in an AppMaker App and so I added this console.log statement to see what it was returning.

```
function getTodaysDate(){
  console.log('Time Zone is ',Session.getScriptTimeZone());
  return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MMM d, yyyy HH:mm");
}
```

Here's the return:

`Sat Dec 09 09:54:38 GMT-700 2017 Time Zone is America/Los_Angeles`

However, I live in another timezone. In fact, you you can **see my time zone** in the **console log response.**

> The problem is that I don't know where to change this in App Maker and the instructions that pop with code completion seem to refer to the old script editor and not the App Maker Editor.

[image]

> So for now I'm not using Session.getScriptTimeZone() but simply hardwiring it to "GMT-7".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> instructions that pop with code completion seem to refer to the old script editor and not the App Maker Editor

It is totally OK, since App Maker is generating Apps Script apps.

> **File -> Project properties**

You don't access to this configuration, since Apps Script project(App Maker deployment) is hidden/encapsulated by App Maker application and App Maker doesn't provide a way to configure these properties at this time...

Comment: Can I use an Apps Script Library to generate this string with Utlities.formatDate()? If so would it utilize the Project Settings of the library?

Comment: You definitely can use Apps Script Library. I've never tried this, but my gut filling says that it should handle time zone independently.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Duh, I finally realized I should just put the string America/Denver in there.

Answer (score 0):

We have [a video](https://youtu.be/TXJXMXzTkcg) showing how you can solve this with the [AMU Library](https://script.google.com/d/148C-svFP_-50XseKiXFScVM8DgIozY_FALFlzkEtu2fI7l0_yt0FvbOh/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks.  I took a look at this video just yesterday and learned about Google time.  Do you really have to copy the entire AMU library into AppMaker.  Why can't you load it as a library in App Settings?

Comment: You don't need the whole library and can copy out any part that you need. I don't use it as an Apps Script Library because the Auto completes would not work for the client side methods in App Maker. Apps Script Libraries only work on the server side.